# Len function not returning exact number of characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don’t know why my len function is not returning the exact number of characters for a cell formatted in datetime i.e yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss. For instance the number of characters in the cell formatted datetime is 19 but it returns 15

I tried to use the find function to look for specific characters but it gives value error for the cell formatted in datetime

Comment: Datetimes are just (formatted) numbers. `LEN` is giving you the length of the underlying number, not of the format you see.

Comment: Have a look here - https://superuser.com/questions/678934/how-can-i-get-the-displayed-value-of-a-cell-in-ms-excel-for-text-that-was-conv

Comment: Use `TEXT()` function then `LEN()` like `=LEN(TEXT(A1,"MM/DD/YYYY")`.

Comment: An example to show what you are really doing would help.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to work correctly on my Office 365 Excel:
[image]

Comment: Happy coincidence. Change the format to General. Or change it to `mm/dd/yyyy`. `LEN` returns the length of the underlying number, not the formatted text.

Comment: Or use `=TODAY()`. The `LEN` is 5, not 10.

Comment: Guess this points out the for the question to include more detail. But I learned something new today so all is good!

Comment: The datetime is formatted in the cell like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss  i.e  2017-09-01 08:05:45 the total number of text string character is 19 but the len function gives me 15